# how operator overloading works in sorting in cpp?

Tags: c++, sorting, operator-overloading

I know comparators for sorting ,I know that comp(x,y) should
return true to get order ..,x ,....,y.. in a vector.

```
bool comp(int x,int y){
    return occurences[x]<occurences[y];
}
```

sort(data.begin(),data.end(),cmp);
according to x will followed by y in vector (...x..y..)

But recently I get to know about 
same thing using operator overloading regarding which i have some doubts.

```
struct Edge{
    int u,v,weight;
    bool operator < (Edge const& other){
       return weight < other.weight;
    }
}
```

1) will it going to work in the same way?Like here if current edge weight

2)And which will come first ,I mean above in above format comp(x,y) return true
then x will come first But what is the criteria here because it seems that we 
are passing only argument here in the operator overloading function.
Like if we compare Edge1(weight=40) < Edge2(weight=60) then which will come 
first and why?

Comment: Did you write a test and debug it?

Comment: The left-hand operand of your operator is `*this`, and `other` is the right-hand one.

Comment: `bool operator<(Edge const& other){` should be `bool operator<(Edge const& other) const {`, it's not going to work without the extra `const`. It's better to declare `operator<` as a free function however.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring a member function of a class, there is an "invisible" first argument : `this`

So outside the class the function looks something like:

```
bool operator < (const Edge* this, Edge const& other)
        { return this->weight < other.weight; }
```

So the left (first) variable is always `this` and the right (second) variable  is `other`.

Another way to look at is like Aconcagua has suggested:

An expression `x < y` is mapped to `Edge x, y; x.operator<(y);` – this is calling the operator explicitly.

For more details about operator overloading: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: For comparison: calling the operator explicitly: `Edge x, y; x.operator<(y);` – this is what `x < y` actually is mapped to...

Comment: then if returns true then this->weight will come first ?

Comment: @user12345 Yes. True. `this->weight` is smaller than `other.weight`. So it will be sorted before `other`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't give `std::sort` a custom comparator, then the range will be sorted by comparing elements using `operator<`.

Logically, there is only a single-line difference between the two versions of `std::sort`:

```
if (obj1 < obj2) {
```

vs

```
if (cmp(obj1, obj2)) {
```

In both instances, objects will be sorted such that for any object `obj1` sorted before another object `obj2`, the comparison will return `true`.